# get frequency on non continuos pandas TimeStamp

Tags: python, pandas

I got a timestap series

```
times= pd.to_datetime(['2018-03-01', '2018-03-02', '2018-03-03', '2018-03-06',
           '2018-03-07', '2018-03-08', '2018-03-09', '2018-03-10',
           '2018-03-13', '2018-03-14',

           '2018-07-19', '2018-07-20', '2018-07-21', '2018-07-24',
           '2018-07-25', '2018-07-26', '2018-07-27', '2018-07-28',
           '2018-07-31', '2018-08-01'])
```

I want to discover the frequency, if is daily, weeky or monthly.

But since is no continuous data, pandas methods only return None.

Any aproach to infer frequencys using non countinuos dates?

Comment: Take the modal value of the difference between timesteps? But no, there isn't anything that can do this out of the box because what you define as `frequency` is not a regular frequency.` `pd.infer_freq` will return `None` meaning `None if no discernible frequency `

Comment: You can see whatever `freq` you want: `times.week` or `times.month` or `times.day` I am not sure if that is what you are asking. [pandas.DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is not continous the frequency is ambiguous. But with

```
s = pd.Series(times)
agg = (s - s.shift(1)).to_frame().groupby(0)[0].agg(len)
```

you get an overview over time offsets and the most frequent value is a candidate for what you are looking for.

**EDIT**

Daily data:

```
agg.idxmax() == pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

Weekly data:

```
agg.idxmax() == pd.Timedelta(days=7)
```

Comment: Not a bad solution. But how I automate the answer to give me day or week?

Comment: YES!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome! Maybe you would like to accept my answer ;-)